# Chrome remote device debugger interface corrupted

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have a strange problem with the remote device debugger tool of Chrome.

I use it for cordova app testing, essentially for the console.log messages in the console tab. The developer tools works.

With some Android smartphone all works well, but when I use Meizu MX6 smartphone, the developer tools interface appears corrupter: tabs are positioned in the wrong location, console has no scrollbars so I can't scroll, if I click a tab all disappears and the debugger window becames white, and so on.

Has anyone esperienced this anomaly?

Thanx,
Steven

Comment: I'm having the same problem using a Galaxy S4, did you ever sort it out? I'm running the latest and greatest version of Chrome on Ubuntu 16.04 (which is 65.0.3325.146 fwiw)

Comment: No, never resolved. When happens I have to use my Meizu the only thing I can do is resize the debugger windows a little bit: the interface continue to be corrupted but in this way I can see the log text (without the scrollbars).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meizu MX6 use Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) which is old enough to cause this problem.

To deal with it I use old Chromium builds as described [here](https://rlz.github.io/programming/2018-04-13/cordova-old-android-debug/)